# Foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type '?' because '?' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I did some updates to a new copy of a database that I am using and generated the edmx file from the database, I fixed a couple stored procs that were giving me issues, however in this one method I keep getting this error

> Error CS1579 foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type '?' because '?' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

and I think its tied in with this error

> Error CS1936 Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'int'.  'Select' not found

I have looked around for a solution to this and haven't really found anything solid.

The method in my DAL that is throwing the error is

```
public List<NewCustomer> GetCustomerToEditByID(int id)
    {
        ExoEntities = new ExoEntities();
        List<NewCustomer> lst = new List<NewCustomer>();

        var query = from a in  ExoEntities.usp_GetCustomerByID(id)
                    select a;

        foreach (var b in query)
        {
            lst.Add(new NewCustomer
            {
                CustomerID = b.CustomerID,
                FirstName = b.FirstName,
                LastName = b.LastName,
                YearBuilt = b.YearBuilt,
                Line1 = b.Line1,
                Line2 = b.Line2,
                City = b.City,
                ZipCode = b.ZipCode,
                StateID = (int)b.StateID,
                StateName = b.StateName,
                County = b.County,
                SubDivisionID = (int)b.SubDivisionID,
                ContactName = b.ContactName,
                Phone = b.Phone,
                OtherPhone = b.OtherPhone,
                Cell = b.Cell,
                Fax = b.Fax,
                Email = b.Email
            });
        }

        return lst;
    }
```

the data class is

```
public class NewCustomer
    {
        public int CustomerID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string DateCreated { get; set; }
        public int CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public string YearBuilt { get; set; }
        public byte IsActive { get; set; }
        public int CustomerTypeID { get; set; }

        // Address
        public string Line1 { get; set; }
        public string Line2 { get; set; }
        public string Line3 { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string ZipCode { get; set; }
        public int StateID { get; set; }
        public string StateName { get; set; }
        public string County { get; set; }
        public int SubDivisionID { get; set; }

        // Contact
        public string ContactName { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public string OtherPhone { get; set; }
        public string Cell { get; set; }
        public string Pager { get; set; }
        public string Fax { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public byte ContactIsActive { get; set; }
    }
```

This is the EF context class for the stored procedure

```
public virtual int usp_GetCustomerByID(Nullable<int> customerID)
    {
        var customerIDParameter = customerID.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("CustomerID", customerID) :
            new ObjectParameter("CustomerID", typeof(int));

        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction("usp_GetCustomerByID", customerIDParameter);
    }
```

and my stored procedure is

```
    Create procedure [dbo].[usp_GetCustomerByID]
(
    @CustomerID int
)
AS
SET NOCOUNT OFF
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED

DECLARE @ERROR_SEVERITY int,
        @MESSAGE varchar(1000),
        @ERROR_NUMBER int,
        @ERROR_PROCEDURE nvarchar(200),
        @ERROR_LINE int,
        @ERROR_MESSAGE nvarchar(4000);

begin try
    select 
          caxref.CustomerID,
          caxref.AddressID,
          customer.FirstName,
          customer.LastName,
          customer.YearBuilt,
          address.Line1,
          address.Line2,
          address.City,
          address.ZipCode,
          address.StateID,
          address.County,
          state.StateName,
          address.SubDivisionID,
          contact.ContactName,
          contact.Phone,
          contact.OtherPhone,
          contact.Cell,
          contact.Fax,
          contact.Email
    from [CustomerAddressXREF] caxref
        left join [Customer] customer on customer.CustomerID = caxref.CustomerID
        left join [Address] address on address.AddressID = caxref.AddressID
        left join [SubDivision] subdivision on subdivision.SubDivisionID = address.SubDivisionID
        left join [CustomerContactXREF] ccxref on ccxref.CustomerID = customer.CustomerID
        left join [Contact] contact on contact.ContactID = ccxref.ContactID
        inner join [State] state on state.StateID = address.StateID
    where customer.CustomerID = @CustomerID

end try
BEGIN CATCH
    SET @ERROR_SEVERITY = ISNULL(ERROR_SEVERITY(),'');
    SET @ERROR_NUMBER = ISNULL(ERROR_NUMBER(),'');
    SET @ERROR_PROCEDURE = ISNULL(ERROR_PROCEDURE(),''); 
    SET @ERROR_LINE = ISNULL(ERROR_LINE(),'');
    SET @ERROR_MESSAGE = ISNULL(ERROR_MESSAGE(),'');

    -- Test if the transaction is uncommittable.
    IF (XACT_STATE()) = -1
        BEGIN
            --PRINT N'The transaction is in an uncommittable state. Rolling back transaction.'
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        END;

    -- Test if the transaction is active and valid.
    IF (XACT_STATE()) = 1
        BEGIN
            --PRINT N'The transaction is committable. Committing transaction.'
            COMMIT TRANSACTION;   
        END;

    SET @MESSAGE = 'Error Occured in Stored Procedure ' + cast(@ERROR_PROCEDURE as varchar(200)) + 
                    '; Line Number ' + cast(@ERROR_LINE as varchar) + 
                    '; Message: [' + cast(@ERROR_NUMBER as varchar) + '] - '
                    + cast(@ERROR_MESSAGE as varchar(255))

    RAISERROR(@MESSAGE, @ERROR_SEVERITY, 1);
END CATCH;
```

I have tested the stored procedure in SSMS and it returns the all the data that I need

So I am not sure where the problem is lying.

I have deleted my EDMX file a couple times and regenerated it from the database, but that isn't working, I still get those 2 errors. Its probably blantantly obvious to a solution, but its not popping out at me

Comment: Try turning `SET NOCOUNT OFF` into `SET NOCOUNT ON`, then regenerating. I really hope this doesn't fix it because that would mean EF is doing something really silly (namely, using the single integer that yields  as the return type), but I've seen other software commit this error before.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, no that didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Your `usp_GetCustomerByID` C# function returns a single `int` value, not a collection of objects, so you can't use it as the source of a query.  `from a in  ExoEntities.usp_GetCustomerByID(id)` is not valid.

The return type of `usp_GetCustomerByID` should be an `IEnumerable<sometype>` if you want to query it.  You *might* me able to use `IEnumerable<NewCustomer>` as the return type but it's not clear if that is your entity type.  Then you wouldn't have to iterate it and create new `NewCustomer` objects.  You could just call `return usp_GetCustomerByID(id).ToList()`

Also, the query `from a in <source> select a` is essentially returning an iterator over `<source>`, so you could just use:

```
foreach (var b in <source>)
```

Comment: I'm getting confused, I have other methods set up this way and they are not throwing any errors. For example I have a GetVendorByID(id) and it works fine and is almost identical to the usp_GetCustomerByID(id) in the edmx context class.
I tried creating it as IEnumerable, didn't work and tried just returning it as you mentioned but that threw an error

Comment: @Chris does `GetVendorByID` return an `int`?  There's no way to enumerate over or query a single value so I don't see how that could possibly work.  If you have an example that _does_ work please post a complete, verifiable example.

Comment: Actually there is a difference the usp_GetVendorByID is returning an ObjectResult. I am not understanding why the GetCustomerByID isnt returning an ObjectResult, because when executing the stored procedure in ssms, it does return more than just  the ID

Comment: It _should_ return an `ObjectResult`, or at least not an `int`.  Did you write that C# function or was it generated? If it was generated check the properties in the designer so that it returns the right type.

Comment: I wrote that method, context stuff was auto generated. I removed the stored procedure from the model and model.store and readded and now it is returning an ObjectResult